# jersey 2: how singleton resources are used?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I read Jersey documentation and did not find an answer to a simple question: when I create a singleton resource, how is it used to serve requests?

When serving requests by a singleton resource, does Jersey queue requests and access the singleton instance for each request synchronously, or does Jersey access the same singleton instance concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's access concurrently, so you should make sure that if you want to use a singleton, that the resource class is thread-safe, and any request scope services injected (by field or constructor) are proxied

Comment: please post a reference to documentation explaining proxies. I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think the documentation provide any info on this. You can check out [this article](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/12/injecting-request-scoped-objects-into.html) though.